# How to work with control inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, controls

I use Telerik as a WPF library. We can apply a theme on Telerik controls using application Theme (i.e. theme manager). For Microsoft controls we can set a property to make the theme apply.

The problem is : I don't want to write this line :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Setter Property="telerik:StyleManager.Theme" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.Theme}" />
</Style>
```

for every type: `CheckBox`, `TextBlock`, `TextBox` etc.. for maintenance purpose.

If I target `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">` inheritance doesn't work well.
Base class of CheckBox is Control but when I set property on every control it doesn't set property on every child of control too. Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: Targeting e.g. Control is the right way to do. Can you elaborate on your problem? Do you have a generic Control style as well as specific control styles e.g. for CheckBox?

Comment: If i target type 'Control', it will set the property 'StyleManager.Theme' with the right value, for targetType Control BUT it will not set the property for child of Control, IE : CheckBox for example. It's a strict targeting. I want to target every Control, if possible, every Windows.Control and every Telerik.Control. 

The purpose of this is to change Theme on the fly. It is working, but i don't want to maintain 100+ Setter on specific Control.